# Heimdall errors, "ERROR: Partition "recovery" does not exist in the specified PIT."

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, heimdall

When I try to flash my S4 with Heimdal and put on clockworkmod, i get the follow,

```
$ sudo heimdall flash --recovery ./clockworkmod_6.0.3.2_jfltespr.img --no-reboot
Heimdall v1.4.0

Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/

This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is
encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating:
http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/

Initialising connection...
Detecting device...
Claiming interface...
Attempt failed. Detaching driver...
Claiming interface again...
Setting up interface...

Initialising protocol...
Protocol initialisation successful.

Beginning session...

Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond.
Please be patient!

Session begun.

Downloading device's PIT file...
PIT file download successful.

ERROR: Partition "recovery" does not exist in the specified PIT.
Ending session...
Releasing device interface...
Re-attaching kernel driver...
```

So why is it telling me,

> ERROR: Partition "recovery" does not exist in the specified PIT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heimdall errors, "Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!"](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/heimdall-errors-failed-to-confirm-end-of-file-transfer-sequence)

Comment: For me, the recovery partition was called `Kernel2` on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is because the command you used to invoke heimdall was,

```
heimdall flash --recovery
```

And, heimdall is caps sensitive, try this instead.

```
heimdall flash --RECOVERY ./clockworkmod_6.0.3.2_jfltespr.img --no-reboot
```

Comment: If you get `ERROR: Failed to receive handshake response. Result: -7` after an earlier attempt, reboot the device and try this `heimdall --RECOVERY ...` command again.

Answer (score 12):

My partition was not called recovery but "SOS". You can check it by doing: `heimdall print-pit --verbose` from a terminal while the tab is in Download mode.

I flashed my p7510. Gist: https://gist.github.com/pskiden/6311605