# Is this the right way to use dd for a full backup?

Tags: adb, backup

Sadly my device (sm-g3185) isn't supported by either CWM or NANDbackup, so I am trying to do a backup manually. I found [this thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818321) which tells me to open a terminal (I'm on Arch Linux) and run:

```
adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555
adb shell
su
/system/xbin/busybox nc -l -p 5555 -e /system/xbin/busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0
```

And then open another terminal and run:

```
adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555
cd /path/to/store/the/backup
nc 127.0.0.1 5555 | pv -i 0.5 > mmcblk0.raw
```

I did all this and it seems to be working. However, there was a delay of a few seconds between launching the `dd` command in terminal1 and the `nc` command in terminal2.

Can I trust the backup I created in this way? Doesn't this mean that I've lost some of the output of `dd`? Shouldn't these be run concurrently or, at least, shouldn't the `nc` command be started *before* the `dd` one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can I trust the backup I created in this way?*

Yes, of course! This is the most accurate backup method.

Data integrity can be verified by comparing the outputs of running [`md5sum(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/md5sum.1.html) on both the `/dev/block/mmcblk0` volume on your device and the `mmcblk0.raw` disk image on your computer.

Additionally, you can use [`parted(8)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/parted.8.html) to list all the partitions on the backup file:

```
parted /path/backup/mmcblk0.raw print
```

There you will find your `system` and `userdata` partitions, among many others containing bootloaders, firmware and recovery images.

> *There was a delay of a few seconds between launching the `dd` command on the device and the `nc` on the host computer. Doesn't this mean that I've lost some of the output of `dd`?*
> *Shouldn't these be run concurrently or, at least, shouldn't the `nc` command be started before the `dd` one?*

Don't worry! When you run `nc -l`, it will listen for an inbound connection, blocking the pipe and keeping `dd` from sending data until you establish the connection from your computer.

---

*Note: you don't need to run `adb forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555` twice.*

#### Warning

**Most of the modern devices encrypt all your data. Make sure that you can decrypt the backup file and access your data before erasing the phone.**

Answer (score 1):

I let it run and after it finished, `dd` reported:

```
7818182656 bytes (7.3GB) copied, 1245.237601 seconds, 6.0MB/s
```

And `ls -l mmcblk0.raw` on my computer shows:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 7818182656 Nov 10 14:45 mmcblk0.raw
```

Since the file is the right size, presumably the backup was successful.

Comment: I am still interested in an answer that explain _why_ that worked so I won't accept this for a while. Is there some sort of buffering going on here? How does it work exactly?

Comment: is the .raw the same as a .img?

Comment: @Alexis yes, the extension is irrelevant, I just chose .raw.

Comment: did it end up working for you?  Could you check out my question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/129330/create-burnable-image-of-android?

Comment: @Alexis yes, it worked fine for me. At least, it created a file of the right size which is a good indication. Presumably, the `dd` output was buffered which is why nothing was lost. As for your question, please edit it and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the output of `busybox nc -h` from the Kindle Fire HDX I'm working on:

```
BusyBox v1.20.2 (2013-01-21 11:34:41 CET) multi-call binary.

Usage: nc [-iN] [-wN] [-l] [-p PORT] [-f FILE|IPADDR PORT] [-e PROG]

Open a pipe to IP:PORT or FILE

        -e PROG Run PROG after connect
        -l      Listen mode, for inbound connects
                (use -l twice with -e for persistent server)
        -p PORT Local port
        -w SEC  Timeout for connect
        -i SEC  Delay interval for lines sent
        -f FILE Use file (ala /dev/ttyS0) instead of network
```

So, the entire image is received because netcat waits for the connection to be established before running `busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0`, that connection being established by `nc 127.0.0.1 5555` in the second terminal window.