# Create burnable image of Android?

Tags: rom-flashing, backup, twrp, nandroid, flashtool

I'm using a tool to flash an Android device with a .img file.  The tool is called USB Flash Burner.  What this tool does is you boot the Android device up while pressing a paperclip in the reset button.  Then you point the USB Burner Tool to an .img file and it writes over pretty much everything.  Here are the [instructions](http://freaktab.com/forum/tv-player-support/amlogic-based-tv-players/other-aml-s802-s805-devices/21960-rom-download-109k4-stock-firmware-for-mk808b-plus-quad-core-tv-stick-add-usb-lan-support).

> If you want to use the Amlogic USB Burning tools to update, please download the firmware here:
>
> http://pan.baidu.com/s/1mgl3R40
>
> firmware update instruction for update via usb buring tool is here:
>
> http://blog.geekbuying.com/index.php/2014/11/24/how-to-flash-stock-firmware-on-mk808b-plus-quad-core-tv-stick/
>   please note, you should use the newest usb burning tool, download it here:
>   http://www.mediafire.com/download/zo7b5cy0nzb7o91/Amlogic_USB_Burning_Tool_New_Version.rar
>
> If you want to use SD card to do the update, please download the firmware here:
>   http://pan.baidu.com/s/18OSRc 
>   password: 9qca

Now my questions is how do I make my own .img file that I can use with the USB Burner Tool?  Is the file that I burn using the USB Burner Tool a ROM?  Firmware?  And how do I go about creating the .img file needed?  I need to make my own because I have to make a version that I can flash for other people.  The devices of the other people are all exactly the same.

I already used TWRP to make a backup, and it give me `boot.emmc.win`, `data.ext4.win`, `data.info`, `system.ext4.win`, and `system.info`.  This works but I have to insert the sd card in and press a bunch of buttons to make the recovery work.  We deal with a lot of devices and with the USB Burner Tool it is faster and brings the device back if it is really bricked.

Thanks for any help!  Also if you have pointers to help that would be appreciated about where I can look.

Comment: What is it you want to install? What would you be making an image of? Your existing system? Another one? What makes you think it would be compatible with your device? What are "other p"? Other people? With different devices? Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do more clearly.

Comment: @terdon I have a golden image on one device.  I'm looking to make a complete copy of the system (apps, os, settings, ...everything)  The other devices are exactly the same as the golden device.  We have a bunch of the exact same device we give to people.  Sometime though the devices get bricked and I wipe them and refresh them with an SD card solution.

Comment: OK, please [edit] your question to make that clear. All relevant information needs to be in the question itself. And yes, [using `dd`](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/128468/86635)  on the device file should work.