# Not possible to make complete backup of my phone without wiping it?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, backup, linux

Phone: Fairphone 2 (Android 6.0.1)
OS on Laptop: Linux Mint

To get a complete backup of my phone I want to follow the suggestions here:
[Is this the right way to use dd for a full backup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128468/is-this-the-right-way-to-use-dd-for-a-full-backup)

For this I have to be root first, otherwise I can not do this, right?

So is there no way to get root **without** wiping your whole device?
My problem is that I have nicely configured and set up my device but want to do complete backups from now on.

Comment: Rooting itself does not wipe anything...  Unlocking the Bootloader does and, other than a few devices with specific exploits, is a requirement to wipe the device.

Comment: It is correct that you cannot perform a complete backup without either rooting the device or installing a custom recovery. The latter definitely requires to unlock the bootloader, which usually (very few exceptions known) implicates a factory reset (wipe). As for rooting, you might want to ask, specifically for your device, how to root it. As it is not yet listed in [our rooting index](/q/1184/16575), that question is permitted (we have the policy of one "how-to-root" question per device).