# Heimdall 1.4.0 (Final) error "Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!” on Galaxy S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, att, heimdall, cyanogenmod

Using Heimdall 1.4.0 on Mavericks on a Galaxy S4 SGH-I337 to flash CWM, I get:

> sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY
>   recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.4.7-jflteatt.img --no-reboot Password:
>   Heimdall v1.4.0
>
> Copyright (c) 2010-2013, Benjamin Dobell, Glass Echidna
>   http://www.glassechidna.com.au/
>
> This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution
>   is encouraged.
>
> If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
>   development please consider donating:
>   http://www.glassechidna.com.au/donate/
>
> Initialising connection... Detecting device... Claiming interface...
>   Setting up interface...
>
> Initialising protocol... Protocol initialisation successful.
>
> Beginning session...
>
> Some devices may take up to 2 minutes to respond. Please be patient!
>
> Session begun.
>
> Downloading device's PIT file... PIT file download successful.
>
> Uploading RECOVERY 100% ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer
>   sequence! ERROR: RECOVERY upload failed!
>
> Ending session... Releasing device interface...

Aware of the response, but it seems to have been triggered by the RC1 version of heimdall.
[Heimdall errors, "ERROR: Failed to confirm end of file transfer sequence!"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/heimdall-errors-error-failed-to-confirm-end-of-file-transfer-sequence)

I'm directly connected with no USB cable.

Comment: What do you mean when you say *"I'm directly connected with no USB cable"*?